# C++ Pass by value/reference

Tags: c++

I have the following code snippet:

```
vector<DEMData>* dems = new vector<DEMData>();
ConsumeXMLFile(dems);

if(!udp_open(2500))
{

}
```

I want the ConsumeXMLFile method to populate the vector with DEMData objects built from reading an XML file.  When ConsumeXMLFile returns, the dems vector is empty.  I think I'm running into a pass by value problem.

Comment: What's the full signature of the ConsumeXMLFile method? I assume that accepts a pointer.

Comment: The signature is "void ConsumeXMLFile(vector<DEMData>* dems)"

Comment: Have you stepped through `ConsumeXMLFile()` with a debugger?

Comment: Post the code for ConsumeXMLFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you at any point reassigning the pointer that is passed into the function? In other words, does your function look anything like this:

```
void ConsumeXMLFile(vector<DEMData>* dems) 
{
   // ... some code ...

   dems = new vector<DEMData>();

   // ...more code...
}
```

This is a common mistake that I see beginning C++ programmers (and C programmers) make. What is going on here is that *a pointer to the dems vector is being passed by value*, which means that if you modify the pointed-to vector, that will affect the the vector possessed by the caller. However if you modify the *pointer* (which is passed by *value*) this will not affect the pointer possessed by the caller. After the re-assignment, the dems pointer in ConsumeXMLFile will point to a totally different vector than the dems pointer that the caller holds.

One of the things that makes me suspect that you might be doing this is that this is C++ and there's no clear reason why you would want to pass a pointer to the vector instead of a reference to the vector otherwise.

Comment: As Tyler says, passing by reference is a much safer way to pass objects. But if you really must use pointers you can make the param a const pointer to the vector: void ConsumeXMLFile(vector<DEMData>* const dems)

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of this the ConsumeXMLFile takes a pointer to a vector so I doubt this is a pass by value problem.